# Access multiple activities

Tags: android

How am i to access two activities(service and Fragment activity) with one button click..without button it is working very well but with button its not...and my project their must be a button included.
MY service code is here i have to run this also with my other activity

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context context;
    boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
    boolean canGetLocation=false;
    Location location;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context)
    {
     this.context=context;
    }
```

Comment: give detail, about your code, post your activity and service so we can understand what you want

Comment: This is not the correct way for location, many things have changed in newer version check that out.